# UITableView with custom index view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

What I'm trying to do is to customize the look of UITableView index. After some search I came to the conclusion that this is not possible and I have to make a custom view to accomplish something like the screen shot below.

[example http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/8573/57screenshot20111231at9.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/8573/57screenshot20111231at9.png)

My table view doesn't have sections, so what I want to do is to scroll one "page" down or up when one of the little dots is tapped. Also I want the user to be able to swipe over the view to jump over pages quickly just like the standard table view index.

I will be grateful if you provide me with an example of something similar to this or at least some guidelines on where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you don't mind the 'dots' being a fixed colour, this is indeed possible to accomplish with the already provided methods. You need only use the 2 methods:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

You will also need a `UIImageView` that holds the transparent image you have over the selected 'dot'.

In the first method, return an `NSArray` for the form: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@".", @".", ..., @".", nil];`. This will enter in 'dots' in the side bar, where each dot represents 1 section of the `UITableView`. When the user taps on one of the 'dots', the `UITableView` will move to the corresponding section. Since you want the sections to be each 1 page length, just section your data accordingly.

As for the second method, this is where you adjust the frame of the `UIImageView` holding the transparent image which covers the selected dot. Just change the `.frame.` property to line up with the new selected section. You'll need to do a bit of math to get this lined up right, but it's fairly easy.

You'll also need to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to handle moving the transparent image while the user is scrolling. They are:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

These will allow you to have the `UIImageView` move to the appropriate section while the user is scrolling. Again, you'll have to do a bit of math to get everything lined up perfectly.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try that. The only problem I have is that my TableView is a single section. If I split it to multiple sections, do I have to have a header for each section or I could make it show as one big section?

Comment: You do not need a header for each section. Just return `nil` in the `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;` method.